# datepicker dialog values becomes empty

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

hey guys I need help with datepicker dialog because I was saving the values of it in to a variables inside onDateSet: "selectedYear", "selectedMonth", "selectedDay"
those are the variable which are declared as private within the class. My issue is after formatting the date using format date function the values of the variable are back to empty thats why I created a new function where I can save them which I know is a messy move, I would like to know guys why are the variables getting empty and what is a better fix for this code. thanks in advanced

```
 datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                selectedYear = year;
                selectedMonth = monthOfYear;
                selectedDay = dayOfMonth;
                setDateEdit.setText(formatDate(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay));
            }
        }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


private String formatDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        saveDateToVar(year,month,day);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        cal.set(year, month, day);
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        return sdf.format(date);
    }



  private void saveDateToVar(int year, int month, int day){
        savedYear = year;
        savedDay = day;
        savedMonth = month;
    }
```

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960426/datepicker-dialog-box-does-not-open-on-click/32961832#32961832 for date and time piker dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and modify according to your needs. This will help you to open date picker to select date.

```
public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        month = month + 1;
        textView.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
    }
}
```

You can set either date or month or year separately with code.
You have to call that method in this way.

```
btn_showDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DateDialog();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }
    });
```

When you click on "OK" displayed date automatically set on textView.

Happy code and Happy to help. :)

Comment: in my code Im going to use "selectedYear", "selectedMonth", "selectedDay" for other purposes thats why I need to get it using other functions. Thanks anyway.